# Can anyone calculate KK(A,B) when neither A or B are the complex numbers?

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, oa.operator-algebras

Here I am referring to Kasparov's KK-theory, a bivariant functor on the category of separable C* algebras.  It is well known that $KK(A, \mathbb{C})$ is K-homology and $KK(\mathbb{C}, B)$ is K-theory, both of which can be calculated for a huge collection of C* algebras (often by topological methods).

I am wondering if anybody knows how to actually calculate $KK(A,B)$ when it is not simply isomorphic to K-theory or K-homology (so I guess I also have to exclude $C_0(\mathbb{R})$.  It seems that most of the time the interest in KK groups is not actually calculating them but in constructing specific elements (such as the Dirac / dual Dirac elements in proofs of the Baum-Connes conjecture).

It occurred to me that I have never actually seen anybody explicitly calculate $KK(A, B)$ in nontrivial cases.  I am left wondering if this is because nobody knows how to do it or if it just isn't particularly useful to do so.  Explanations or references are both appreciated.

Comment: $KK(\mathbb C \oplus \mathbb C,\mathbb C \oplus \mathbb C) = M_2 \mathbb Z$.

Comment: When I attended a course by Jacek  Brodzki (http://toknotes.mimuw.edu.pl/sem6/index.html) he indeed said that most of the time we'd be interested not in computing KK(A,B) but rather in understanding specific cycles. But I can't say whether he meant it generally, or only for the lecture (back then I though he meant it generally).

Comment: @Andreas: is this more general statement true: $KK(A^m,A^n)=M_{n,m} (KK(A;A))$?

Comment: @JohannesEbert Even though the question is older, using finite additivity of KK in both variables, I guess the statement is true. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is Rosenberg-Schochet universal coefficient theorem, which says $KK(A,B)\simeq Ext(K_{\ast}(A),K_{\ast+1}(B))\oplus Hom(K_{\ast}(A),K_{\ast}(B))$ (not canonically) when $A$ is $KK$-equivalent to a commutative algebra.  It was proved in *The Künneth theorem and the universal coefficient theorem for Kasparov’s generalized K-functor*, Duke Math. J., 55(1987), 431–474.

Comment: * gets interpreted as code for italics, so you should use \ast on MO instead.  Hopefully I formatted that correctly.

Comment: This is indeed the sort of thing I had in mind - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Hi Paul, I do not know if this is interesting (enough) for you, but in 'The operator K-functor and extensions of C*-algebras' Kasparov shows that for suitable A and B (I guess A,B seperable, A nuclear) there exists an isomorphism from $\mathrm{KK}(A,B)$ onto a group $\mathrm{Ext}(A,C_0(\mathbb{R})\otimes B)$ of 'stable equivalence classes of extensions' 
$$0\xrightarrow{}{} C_0(\mathbb{R})\otimes B\otimes\mathcal{K}\xrightarrow{}{} C \xrightarrow{}{} A \xrightarrow{}{} 0\text{ .}$$.
Maybe the RHS is not concrete enough for this to qualify as an answer.

Comment: Hi Dan!  This is indeed a useful answer as well, though as you feared I don't really know how to concretely describe extension groups for C* algebras, either.  If you know any good tools for computing extension groups for the sorts of C* algebras which make your isomorphism work, that would interest me as well.